# How to give Csharp Webbrowser default Path to download files

Tags: c#, browser, dialog

I am making a web browser in C Sharp, I want that all the files downloaded by the user on this web browser from any web sites, web browser saves it in one default folder (i.e C:\Users\Abc\Downloads)

Currently when i try to download file from any url it pops up a dialogue box asking for path, and it is annoying thing to have so i just wants to give one default path where it just saves the file automatically without asking user for the path.

Like we have default download path for Mozila firefox and google whenever user download any file from the web browser it saves in one default folder. so how can I achieve this in .net 4.0 Csharp web browser.

Comment: Are you using the web browser control in your C# project or are you building a browser from scratch?

Comment: I'm developing it from scratch, and took some reference from Code project

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't with the webbrowser control, 
maybe take a look at

http://www.mono-project.com/WebBrowser

first you don't use IE, and you can do more if I'm right

Regards,

Corné

Comment: thank you for replying, I am using Csharp web browser and i think by default it is using IE settings ... do you know how to change it ??

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the WebBrowser control in c# this can be somewhat of a challenge, but have a look at this link which might help you, I've tried it myself with good results.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31163/Suppressing-Hosted-WebBrowser-Control-Dialogs

Good Luck! :)

Edit:
You might want to look into this solution to your issue as well:

[Automated filedownload using WebBrowser without url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145426/automated-filedownload-using-webbrowser-without-url)

:)